# How to skip spacing in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-express

I try to read the txt file and then convert it to binary then save into array. 
Can anyone help me with this?
The coding below is just a part of my coding. For the coding below, when I entered AB, the answer is correct. If I enter A B, the answer is 1010 and end. It cannot process to the B. It stops when it has spacing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

 int main()
{
long int i=0;
char hexdec[100];
cout<<"Enter any hexadecimal number : ";
cin>>hexdec;
cout<<"\nEquivalent Binary value is : ";
while (hexdec[i])
{
if (hexdec[i]!=NULL)
{
    cout<<hexdec[i]<<endl;
    switch(hexdec[i])
    {
        case '0' : cout<<"0000";
            break;
        case '1' : cout<<"0001";
            break;
        case '2' : cout<<"0010";
            break;
        case '3' : cout<<"0011";
            break;
        case '4' : cout<<"0100";
            break;
        case '5' : cout<<"0101";
            break;
        case '6' : cout<<"0110";
            break;
        case '7' : cout<<"0111";
            break;
        case '8' : cout<<"1000";
            break;
        case '9' : cout<<"1001";
            break;
        case 'A' : cout<<"1010";
            break;
        case 'B' : cout<<"1011";
            break;
        case 'C' : cout<<"1100";
            break;
        case 'D' : cout<<"1101";
            break;
        case 'E' : cout<<"1110";
            break;
        case 'F' : cout<<"1111";
            break;


        default : cout<<"\nInvalid hexadecimal digit "<<hexdec[i];
    }
    i++;
    cout<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<hexdec[i]<<"pass"<<endl;
    i++;
}
}
getch();
```

}

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::getline()`, and read it. And once you use `std::getline()` to read the entire line of input, it will be your job and your responsibility to write the code that parses everything that's been read, including any spaces, and ignore the spaces. A computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do. If you want your computer to ignore spaces in a line of input that it just read, you must write the code that does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Per cplusplus.com, extraction from std::cin always considers spaces as terminating the value being extracted.

[Basic Input/Output](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)

I recomment including the `<string>` header and using `getline` and processing the full line of characters entered.

ex.

```
std::string chars;

std::getline(std::cin,chars); 
// Process chars.c_str()
```

Answer (score 1):

As jschroedl already said, `std:cin` considers spaces as terminating value in which it extracts values before the space. And to use `getline`

To answer your main question (Skip spacing) you could use the syntax

`std::replace( [string].begin(), [string].end(), '[char1]', '[char2]');`

where [string] is your string to have replacements (`hexdec` in your case)

```
char1 = ' ' (space)

char2 = '' (empty)
```

Since hexdec is a character array. You could make it a datatype string since it is basically the same to be manipulated with indices  with addition for the fact that it is available to be used in string headers.